# Forma correta de atualizar um Model a partir de um ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte dúvida: recebo um *ViewModel* no *Controller* do ASP.NET. No método atualizar tenho duas opções:

- 1º opção : transferir o *ViewModel* para a respectiva entidade do banco diretamente e atualizar.
- 2º opção : Buscar primeiro pelo id do objeto a ser atualizado e depois transferir o *ViewModel* para a respectiva entidade do banco e atualizar.

Qual seria a maneira correta de se fazer?

Comment: cara, da uma olhadinha nesses links http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/
http://eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-utilizando-automapper-com-view-model-pattern/
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3
http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/design-patterns/o-que-e-e-como-utilizar-o-padrao-view-model-em-um-projeto-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: A primeira opção seria criar uma tabela no banco com os dados da ViewModel?

Answer (score 3):

Depende da tecnologia do banco.

### Usando Entity Framework

A opção 1 é melhor. Ao mapear seu *ViewModel* para um *Model* e marcar a entrada para alteração, o Entity Framework confere se esta entidade, com a chave primária fornecida, existe. Se existir, ao comandar o `SaveChanges` do contexto, a entidade é atualizada.

Como o Entity Framework confere tudo para você, a opção 2 é desnecessária.

### Usando outro método

Aí é o caso de você buscar a entidade no banco, alterá-la e salvá-la (método 2), a não ser que este outro método seja um ORM que faça este trabalho por você.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano era uma dúvida que fiquei tive que acabar com ela hoje  haha.